# How to get parameter name in aspectj advice class?

Tags: reflection, annotations, aop, spring-el

I am asking this question with my limited knowledge of java reflection and AOP.

**Background:**

I am using annotation based advice in my Java 7 application. Further to get the method parameter which I need to use in my advice I am using spring EL. See below examples:
In first example i want to use second parameter to do my work, whereas in second example I am using a POJO and want to use its "id" field.

```
@MyAnnotation(param = "args[1]")
public void someMethod(int param1, String param2) {
  return null;
}

@MyAnnotation(param = "args[0].id")
public void someMethod(SomeObject someObject) {
  return null;
}
```

But what I actually want is, to get my hands on the parameter names in my AOP. So that I can use *@MyAnnotation(param = "param1")* or *@MyAnnotation(param = "someObject.id")* instead.

From what I have known, you can not get parameter name using reflection. But recently I came across Spring cache abstraction([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)), where I see:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="books", key="#isbn")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

Can someone put some light here, how I can achieve similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

See `MethodBasedEvaluationContext` and `ParameterNameDiscoverer`.

`CacheEvaluationContext` is a subclass of `MethodBasedEvaluationContext`.

[Code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/expression/MethodBasedEvaluationContext.java#L86)...

```
    // Expose indexed variables as well as parameter names (if discoverable)
    String[] paramNames = this.parameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(this.method);
    int paramCount = (paramNames != null ? paramNames.length : this.method.getParameterCount());
    int argsCount = this.arguments.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < paramCount; i++) {
        Object value = null;
        if (argsCount > paramCount && i == paramCount - 1) {
            // Expose remaining arguments as vararg array for last parameter
            value = Arrays.copyOfRange(this.arguments, i, argsCount);
        }
        else if (argsCount > i) {
            // Actual argument found - otherwise left as null
            value = this.arguments[i];
        }
        setVariable("a" + i, value);
        setVariable("p" + i, value);
        if (paramNames != null) {
            setVariable(paramNames[i], value);
        }
    }
```